# Javascript - Built-in Like with Parameters on POST URL

Tags: post, parameters, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I'm making a single page site and I need to put different built-in likes on it but every like will get the og tags from the main page.

How could I pass this parameters to my POST?
Something like:

```
FB.api(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes',
    'post',
    {
        'object': 'http://www.example.com',
        'access_token': token,
        **'Title' : 'The Title'**,
        **'Description' : 'The Description'**
    },
    function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response.error);
        } else {
        }
    };
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're posting the 'like' action against needs to have the correct meta tags for that URL.

It doesn't matter where you post the like action from or what URL the user is actually on when they Like that URL, but the URL you're liking must serve valid meta tags at that URL to Facebook's crawler.

You can see what the crawler is detecting for a URL via [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: Ok, but I have one page with many sections. It's just 1 URL but I want to LIKE just one section. "Guilherme Barchik likes SECTION (http://mysite.com/#section) on APP-NAME" and not "Guilherme Barchik likes SITE (http://mysite.com/) on APP-NAME"

Comment: My answer is complete, you need a URL which serves the meta data for each object to Facebook - if you decide to redirect other traffic from that URL (let's say `mysite.com/product1`) to `mysite.com/#product1` that's fine, but mysite.com/product1 must return the meta tags when the crawler accesses it